# Query in Elasticsearch to return all results for a given phrase

Tags: java, grails, groovy, elasticsearch, lucene

I am using the below code to query the Elasticsearch index but I am not getting back all of the documents matching a given phrase. It returns back specific documents when we search for that particular specific documents For example if I were to ask for phrase 'groovy', it is not bringing me back all the documents with name field groovy. But If I were to search for 'Help.groovy', it gives me back just Help.groovy. Appreciate if someone could help me.

```
private def performSearchUsingElasticSearch(String q) {
    def escaped =  QueryParser.escape(q.toLowerCase().trim())
    def result = elasticSearchService.search(escaped)
    return result
}
```

**Sample Documents**

```
 "hits": [
 {
    "_index": "a.b.c.d",
    "_type": "svnInfo",
    "_id": "183",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
       "author": "abc1200",
       "name": "VendorSpec.groovy",
       "svnUrl": "http://svnrepo/tools/VendorSpec.groovy",
       "date": "Wed May 13 09:35:05 EDT 2015"
    }
 },  {
    "_index": "a.b.c.d",
    "_type": "svnInfo",
    "_id": "184",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
       "author": "abc1200",
       "name": "Help.groovy",
       "svnUrl": "http://svnrepo/tools/Help.groovy",
       "date": "Wed May 13 09:35:05 EDT 2015"
    }
```

Comment: could you please provide mappings for your fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard Analysis will not break tokens at the period when preceded and followed by letters (See section [4.1 of UAX #29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Default_Word_Boundaries), particularly rules [WB6 and WB7](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#WB6)).

You might want to consider a different analyzer.  [`simple`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html) may be a good choice.  Rather than implementing that text segmentation standard, it simply defines tokens as sequences of adjacent letters, which looks like it might be what you want.